# Autodesk Forge API a-401 Error

Tags: node.js, http-status-code-401, autodesk, forge, autodesk-forge

I'm trying to make a simple forge test work.

I am been using this basic git project:
https://github.com/leefsmp/view.and.data-boilerplate

what i did so far:

1. i created an account.
2. implemented the creds in the config file
3. uploaded a file to models.autodesk.io using my secret key.
   4 i took the udn and passed it into the viewer.js file.
4. ran npm install
5. npm run

when i go to the localhost:3000 i still get :

dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bW9kZWwyMDE2LTExLTExLTEyLTQxLTA3LXlldmJwbHl0Yzkya3Y2cGtqdW10Z2F5ZnJ3dTAvUkEtUy1CdWlsZGluZy5ydnQ:1 GET https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0cz…TEyLTQxLTA3LXlldmJwbHl0Yzkya3Y2cGtqdW10Z2F5ZnJ3dTAvUkEtUy1CdWlsZGluZy5ydnQ 401 (Unauthorized)
viewer.js:210 Access was denied to a network resource (HTTP 403).

The buttons for the load and unload extension are visible.

any ideas what i'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking at a deprecated repo, if you want to start with the use of boilerplate samples of the API this is a better option for you.

https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-boilers.nodejs

Comment: Thanks a lot that solved my issue, If  i can ask one more question, any chance you know where i can get an updated version of the 3d/2d display project of forge.  i found ot, on https://developer.autodesk.com/ in the lower right section of the screen, but it seems the fileand the git isn't working any more.

Comment: Here is the link for the sample you are looking for: https://github.com/Developer-Autodesk/viewer-navigation.sample

Comment: Are these boilers still current? I know that at least the first demo has been stripped of functionality provided by now-copyrighted code. Having lots of issues getting #6 to run as well.

Comment: Hi Jackalope, I debugged myself Boiler number 6 last week, what issues are you experiencing. When problems are found feel free to add it as an issue directly on the repo.

Comment: I've been having lots of troubles even just getting authenticated. I carefully followed directions regarding the HOST_URL, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, etc, but always get a "CANNOT GET" error.